# From a big json variable to objects

Tags: python, list, dictionary, typeerror, python-3.9

I have a rather large json stream from which I want to pull data and turn this data into objects, or a dictionary maybe.

I've managed to, for a start pull 4 lists out of the data: admin_fname, admin_sname, admin_type, and admin_email.
Now I have 4 lists of equal length, and I want to further mangle this data so I get objects containing the fname, sname, type and e-mail of an an admin.

I've tried the following:

```
data = response.json()
admins = [item['admin_user'] for item in data['orgs']]
admin_fname = [item['firstname'] for item in admins]
admin_sname = [item['surname'] for item in admins]
admin_type =  [item['type'] for item in admins]
admin_email =  [item['primary_email'] for item in admins]

admin_data = {}

for (a, b, c, d) in zip(admin_fname, admin_sname, admin_type, admin_email):
    admin_data[admin_fname].append()
    admin_data[admin_sname].append()
    admin_data[admin_type].append()
    admin_data[admin_email].append()
```

But, maybe not surprisingly, I get the error "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

Can someone tell me a better way of combining elements of all 4 lists/sets into coherent objects?

Comment: can you share the json (just a small subset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two common problems here. How to represent a single data point, and how to store those data points.

## Representing a single data point

You have a large range of options, but I'm just going to highlight 3:

#### Tuple

You can treat your object as a set of values in a specific order. You already have this with this line:

```
for (a, b, c, d) in zip(admin_fname, admin_sname, admin_type, admin_email):
```

With some better naming:

```
for (fname, sname, type, email) in zip(admin_fname, admin_sname, admin_type, admin_email):
```

Or using the tuple:

```
for admin in zip(admin_fname, admin_sname, admin_type, admin_email):
```

And you can access each of these fields with indexing like this:

```
email = admin[3]
```

However, knowing which data is which index can get difficult after some time.

#### Dictionary

You can represent each data point as a dictionary. You just need to assign each field to a key:

```
for (fname, sname, type, email) in zip(admin_fname, admin_sname, admin_type, admin_email):
    admin = {
        "fname": fname,
        "sname": sname,
        "type": type,
        "email": email,
    }
```

And then, you can access each field with the key:

```
email = admin["email"]
```

However, string keys are still quite error prone

#### Create a class

The most OOP way of doing this would be to create a class:

```
class Admin:
    def __init__(self, fname, sname, type, email):
        self.fname = fname
        self.sname = sname
        self.type = type
        self.email = email
```

And then create an object:

```
for (fname, sname, type, email) in zip(admin_fname, admin_sname, admin_type, admin_email):
    admin = Admin(fname, sname, type, email)
```

and you can access each field as you do on objects:

```
email = admin.email
```

Using a data class is also a good option, as [@balderman suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69000929/4441404)

## Storing the data

Now, how do you store this data:

#### List

Most straight forward, is to put it back in a list of the same order.

With tuples:

```
admins = [t for t in zip(admin_fname, admin_sname, admin_type, admin_email)]
```

With dictionaries:

```
admins = [{"fname": fname, "sname": sname, "type": type, "email": email} for (fname, sname, type, email) in zip(admin_fname, admin_sname, admin_type, admin_email)]
```

With object:

```
admins = [Admin(fname, sname, type, email) for (fname, sname, type, email) in zip(admin_fname, admin_sname, admin_type, admin_email)]
```

You can then access each individual point with an index

#### Dictionary

You can store all your data in a dictionary. However, at that point you need to decide on a unique key to represent each datapoint. For your purposes, that is probably not the best idea.

Comment: Thank you very much for this extensive answer.
The intention is to save the data in an excel or csv file. 
That's another bridge I'll have to cross, but seems way more trivial.

Comment: Yes! This last one worked as I was thinking.
When I do a `print(admins[<index>].<attribute>)`, I get what I'm expecting.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> I have a rather large json stream from which I want to pull data and turn this data into objects, or a dictionary maybe.

I think this is the direction to go

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List

data = [{'admin_fname': 'Jack', 'admin_sname': 'Ken', 'admin_type': 'the_type', 'admin_email': 'kk@some.com'},
        {'admin_fname': 'Dan', 'admin_sname': 'Borg', 'admin_type': 'the_type', 'admin_email': 'zz@some.com'}]


@dataclass
class Admin:
    admin_fname: str
    admin_sname: str
    admin_type: str
    admin_email: str


admins: List[Admin] = [Admin(**entry) for entry in data]
print(admins)
```

output

```
[Admin(admin_fname='Jack', admin_sname='Ken', admin_type='the_type', admin_email='kk@some.com'), Admin(admin_fname='Dan', admin_sname='Borg', admin_type='the_type', admin_email='zz@some.com')]
```

Comment: The json set is really large, and I see myself pulling several classes out of it, but this is a very nice solution. thank you.

Comment: @Bokkie I am glad I managed to help. Feel free to up vote.

Comment: I need more reputation before I can upvote... 8-(

Comment: OK. Good luck with the reputation :-)

Comment: I'm getting an error when I plug this in...

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File <path>, line 42, in <module>
    admins: List[Admin] = [Admin(**entry) for entry in data]
  File <path>, line 42, in <listcomp>
    admins: List[Admin] = [Admin(**entry) for entry in data]
TypeError: __main__.Admin() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str`

Comment: I'm going to go with the object method as @tituszban explained. I'm getting good results with it.
But I will further study cases to see if I can implement your solution somewhere. 
Thanks again for answering.